# CreateListingRequiresSignerError [MetaplexError]: AuctionHouse > Create Listing Requires Signer

Tags: metaplex-js, react, auction-house

I create a list, but when passing and creating a list, an error comes out:

CreateListingRequiresSignerError [MetaplexError]: AuctionHouse > Create Listing Requires Signer

> > Source: Plugin > AuctionHouse
> > Problem: You are trying to create a listing without providing a signer.
> > Solution: Either a seller or authority must be a Signer.

```
at Object.createListingBuilder (C:\Users\SUMBAR\Visual Studio Code Project\mint-fungible-spl\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\auctionHouseModule\operations\createListing.ts:314:11)
at AuctionHouseBuildersClient.list (C:\Users\SUMBAR\Visual Studio Code Project\mint-fungible-spl\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\auctionHouseModule\AuctionHouseBuildersClient.ts:100:12)
at C:\Users\SUMBAR\Visual Studio Code Project\mint-fungible-spl\mint.ts:161:61
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at C:\Users\SUMBAR\Visual Studio Code Project\mint-fungible-spl\mint.ts:8:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (C:\Users\SUMBAR\Visual Studio Code Project\mint-fungible-spl\mint.ts:4:12)
at createListing (C:\Users\SUMBAR\Visual Studio Code Project\mint-fungible-spl\mint.ts:157:5)
at C:\Users\SUMBAR\Visual Studio Code Project\mint-fungible-spl\mint.ts:285:9
at Generator.next (<anonymous>) {
```

key: 'metaplex.errors.plugin.auction_house.create_listing_requires_signer',
title: 'AuctionHouse > Create Listing Requires Signer',
problem: 'You are trying to create a listing without providing a signer.',
solution: 'Either a seller or authority must be a Signer.',
source: 'plugin',
sourceDetails: 'AuctionHouse',
cause: undefined,
logs: undefined
}
Here is the code itself:

const listing = await metaplex2.auctionHouse().list(
{
auctionHouse: auction,
mintAccount: mintAccount,
price: price,
seller: metaplex.identity().publicKey,
},
{}
);
I've already tried everything, but still this error comes out